# Prove that If x and y are integers and x + y is odd , then x−y is odd.

Tags: solution-verification

I am facing a problems with this question : Prove that If x and y are integers and x + y is odd , then x−y is odd. , any suggestions ?

Comment: You can say that $x-y=x+y-2y\equiv x+y\ ({\rm mod}\ 2)\equiv 1\ ({\rm mod}\ 2)$ and thus $x-y$ is also odd.

Comment: This is barely readable.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is wrong because you cannot just **assume** that $x$ is odd. Your proof says nothing about what happens if $x$ is even. You could *separate the cases* (there are four of them) and run the proof over each of those, but there is a much simpler way of proving the statement.

**Hint**:
Use the fact that
$$x-y = (x+y) - 2y.$$

Answer (score 0):

The difference between $x+y$ and $x-y$ is an even number.